# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre dependencias y dependencias de desarrollo en node?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Cuando inicializo npm init e instalo las dependencias, quisiera saber ¿cuál es la diferencia entre `dependencias de desarrollo` y `dependencias`?

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, las preguntas de este tipo pueden abrirse a un sinnumero de respuestas todas en su mayoria validas, lo mejor es que resumas tu pregunta a un problema en especifico. Podrias bien, mostrarnos el error que te arroja el comando `npm` o bien permitirnos a reproducir el mismo problema que estas presentando. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Las `devDependencies` son dependencias que usas solo para la fase de dessarrollo comunmente, tranpiles taskrunner y unit test se manejan como `devDependencies` ej. grunt gulp babel mocha chai etc. estas dependencias no son necesarias en producion y tu aplicacion puede funcionar si ellas.

Los `dependencies` son las que utilizas para que tu proyecto trabaja e.j express monngoose lodash body-parser estas dependencias son parte de la logica de tu aplicacion y son necesarias para que el proyecto funcione correctamente en producion.

Answer (score 2):

Una developer dependency, es una dependencia que sólo se utiliza en la fase de desarrollo

Por ejemplo es normal dotar a tu aplicación una documentación o manuales, no obstante los usuarios suelen requerir manuales en diferentes formatos ej: `texto plano`, `html`, o bien `pdf`. En la práctica resulta molesto tener que desarollar documentos con la misma información por lo que recurres a una aplicación que genere de un solo archivo, los documentos `.txt`, `.html`, `.pdf`. Decimos entonces que nuestro proyecto depende de esa aplicación para generar la documentanción, no obstante el proyecto en sí mismo no requiere de la aplicacion para ejecutarse, a eso se le llama `developer dependency`.

Otro ejemplo:
En los lenguajes compilados generalmente se requiere de otras aplicaciones para compilar tu proyecto, por ejemplo, muchos utilizan `make`, sin ellos no podrás compilar el proyecto, no obstante tu proyecto no depende directamente de él, sólo depende de él en la fase de compilación mas no en su ejecución.

En general

> Una developer dependency es aquella de la que dependes en la fase de desarrollo mas no en la fase de ejecución / distribución

En `node`, una `dev dependency` podría ser `less`, con `less` generarías los hojas de estilo de tu aplicación web, no obstante cuando tu subes tu aplicación web a producción solamente subes los archivos `.css` generados por `less` , como puedes ver tu proyecto no depende de `less` en la fase de ejecución / distribución.

Otro ejemplo en `node` de `dev dependency` podría ser `babel.js`, con `babel.js` transladarías tus `.js` de `ECS6` a `ECS5` no obstante una vez transladados de estándar, el uso de `babel.js` es discutible, por tanto `babel.js` sólo es una `dev dependency`